# Add reference and com directory to visual studio?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, sdk

Visual Studio recently forgot my SQL Server CE SDK installs (they're still there and I tried doing a re-install).

I was just wondering is it possible to add a directory for visual studio to look in for references? Sort of like in C++ how you can have include directories.

Comment: Per project? Or for the IDE itself?

Comment: Does [DevEnv.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7.aspx) /ResetSettings  make any difference in getting Visual Studio to pick up the SQL CE SDK?

Comment: @Mike Atlas I would like it to be the way it was before where the IDE knew where the SQL CE libraries were installed

Comment: @JeremyThompson Sadly that doesn't help, it still won't see the libraries even though they are installed in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a directory for visual studio to look for references:

[Add Reference Search Path Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db34az84.aspx)

"Use this dialog box to specify an additional directory path that the project system will search to resolve references to DLLs, assemblies, or modules in your application."

Comment: I tried adding C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\Devices\ which contains the System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll assembly but when I go to add a reference System.Data.SqlserverCe does not show up in the '.net' tab...

Comment: Interesting coincidence? [i-dont-have-sqlserverce-assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714480/i-dont-have-sqlserverce-assembly)

Comment: sadly that didn't work for me, the SqlCe libraries aren't listed... It's really frustrating because they are installed and I can point at exactly where they are :-/